# C# add to list not working

Tags: c#, function

I am new to C# and I am just trying to create a simple program to perform some basic calculations on VS2010. The problem I'm having is that I don't seem to be able to add the calculated value to a list.

```
List<double> distance = new List<double>();
List<double> speed = new List<double>();

// distance and speed are populated using Add()

List<double> slope = new List<double>();
double rise, run;
for (int i= 0; i< distance.Count(); i++)
{
    rise = 0.0;
    run = 0.0;
    if (i> 0)
    {
        rise = speed[i] - speed[i- 1];
        run = distance[i] - distance[i- 1];

        if (rise == 0 || run == 0)
        {
            slope.Add(0.0);
        }
        else slope.Add(rise/run);

    }
    else slope.Add(0.0);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", i, rise, run, rise/run, slope);
}
```

The resulting output is

```
...
10, -21.7, -0.089, -243.82, System.Collection.Generic.List`1[System.Double]
11, 1.49, -0.088, -16.93, System.Collection.Generic.List`1[System.Double]
12, -4.51, -0.514, 87.74, System.Collection.Generic.List`1[System.Double]
```

All other uses of the `Add()` function have been fine, however, these are all adding elements or averages of another list of the same type.

Why does the `Add()` not like the calculation using two double values? What should I be doing here?

Comment: Well you can't output a List<T>. You need to iterate over the list and output element-by-element.

Comment: try printing `slope[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's not the way to show a list in the console.

Try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<slope.Count;i++)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(slope[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use string.Join to make coma-separated list

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", i, rise, run, rise/run, string.Join(", ", slope));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", i, rise, run, rise/run, slope);
```

All the values you print there are regular numbers—except for `slope`. It is a list that contains numbers out of each iteration. Because it is a more complex type, its `ToString()` method just gives its exact type.

You have two choices here. Either you only print the value you just added to the list, `slope[i]`, or you print the whole list:

```
// print the value
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", i, rise, run, rise/run, slope[i]);

// print the whole list
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", i, rise, run, rise/run, string.Join(", ", slope));
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate to list as follows,

```
foreach(double d in slope)
 Console.WriteLine(d); //or Console.Write(d+" ");
```

You have to do like this because, list not a valid (here valid means the way you wanted to see the output) argument for [Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx). c# will do `.toString()` to the list show the output, hence you see `System.Collection.Generic.List1[System.Double]`. You have to iterate over it.

Comment: A list is a perfectly fine argument for [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e.aspx), and more correctly also a fine argument for [`string.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) otherwise OP’s code would have had a compile-time error.

Comment: What I meant by `valild` was it will not yield expected output. Modifying it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing the text is because your format operation is taking the ToString() method.

Your rise/run division appears to have been assigned the type System.Double rather than the primitive type double, hence ToString() is giving a different result.

There's nothing 'wrong', but you may wish to explicitly use the primitive double type for convenience in this situation.